# Update template with received data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I've managed to retrieve a set of data from a post request, but now the view does not update when I assign it.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'news-section',
  templateUrl: './news-section.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./news-section.component.scss'],
  providers: [ NewsService ],
})
export class NewsSectionComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  slider: any;
  stub: number[];
  articles: NewsItemComponent[];

  constructor(translate: TranslateService, private http: Http, public newsService: NewsService) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    translate.use('en');

    this.articles = [];

    newsService.getNews().subscribe( news => {
        let articles: Array<any> = [];
        news.map((res) => {
            articles.push(new NewsItemComponent(res.text, res.created_at
, 'author', res.id_str);
          });
          console.log('articles', articles);
          this.articles = articles;
      });
  }


}
```

I see in the `console.log` that the articles list is updated correctly but it does not reflect the changes in the view.

```
<section id="news" sectionVisible>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ 'Nav.News' | translate }}</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="news-wrapper clear-fix">
      <div class="column carousel-cell" ngFor="#article of articles">
        <article>
        <a href="#" class="hovered">
          <div class="bg-hover">
            <p>
              Visit
            </p>
          </div>
        </a>
        <h2>News title</h2>
        <time>21.10.2015 16:30</time>
        <p>
          Etiam faucibus sodales leo, rutrum molestie nisi luctus in. Duis quis viverra diam, vitae hendrerit augue. Donec ultricies nisi vel placerat sodales. Donec varius convallis mauris egestas vulputate. Integer fermentum tincidunt hendrerit. Donec eget nisl
          eros. Pellentesque a fringilla lorem.
        </p>
        </article>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

do I need to add some listeners? 
I've looked through http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html  but still my angular knowledge is very basic and need some explanations

Comment: What error message do you get in the browser console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ngFor="#article of articles"
```

should be

```
*ngFor="let article of articles"
```

Comment: Can you describe what is the difference between both ngFors? I assume the second one is bounded to articles, and first one just a pure for?

Comment: The former is entirely invalid because of the missing `*` (`*` indicates a [structural directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html)) and `#` is old syntax that was replaced by `let` a few months ago.

Comment: One thing more, maybe you will also know. Im trying to wrap a slider around the created elements. When using previous value and all elements where rendered the slider was working correctly. Now when I init the slider in subscribe after the whole elements should be rendered It behaves like there would be no elements inside the given container. Is there some timeout or event after the view has changed, to fire the function after the news are updated?

Comment: Can you please create a new question? Please add the code there you're currently using. I have troubles understanding your last comment. What does "wrap a slider around the created elements" mean or "last value" or " to fire the function after the news are updated"?

Comment: Ok nevermind. I've managed to fix the slider by adding a quick timeout in the subscribe after the values of articles are retrieved from the served and passed to the dom. Apparently there is some time before the dom is updated and rebuilt

Comment: If you inject `constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}` and call `cdRef.detectChanges()` then the DOM should be updated when the call returns.